# How to efficiently read data from mongodb and convert it into spark's dataframe?

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have already researched a lot but could not find a solution. Closest question I could find here is [Why my SPARK works very slowly with mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457608/why-my-spark-works-very-slowly-with-mongodb).

I am trying to load a mongodb collection into spark's DataFrame using mongo-hadoop connector. Here is a snippet of relevant code:

```
connection_string = 'mongodb://%s:%s/randdb.%s'%(dbhost, dbport, collection_name)
trainrdd = sc.mongoRDD(connection_string, config=config)
#     traindf = sqlcontext.createDataFrame(trainrdd)
#     traindf = sqlcontext.read.json(trainrdd)
traindf = sqlcontext.jsonRDD(trainrdd)
```

Here, 'sc' is the SparkContext object. I have also tried the variants which are commented out in the code. But all are equally slow. For a collection of size 2GB (100000 rows and 1000 columns), it takes around 6 hours(holy moly :/) on a cluster of 3 machines each with 12 cores and 72 GB RAM (using all the cores in this spark cluster). Mongodb server is also running on one of these machines.

I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.  Any pointers on how to optimize this code would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you referring to the use of `jsonRDD` that is slow ? Can you try converting the RDD to DataFrame through other means ?

Comment: Hi Wan
Thanks for replying. Yes, the actual action starts when you call 'sqlcontext.jsonRDD(trainrdd)'. This triggers the mongodb read, with mongodb logs stating connections being established and dropped. I have tried other methods(commented out in the code above), which are equally slow. Recently, I tried sqlcontext.read.json on a json file exported from mongodb collection. This worked quite fast comparatively.

Comment: Which jar version of the [mongodb mongo-hadoop spark connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/spark/src/main/python/README.rst) are you using ? Can you try separating out MongoDB server from Spark nodes ?

Comment: ok, I will try out separating MongoDB server and will post it here. I am using spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6 and mongo-hadoop 1.5.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Efficient way to read data from mongo using pyspark is to use [MongoDb spark connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python/read-from-mongodb/)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
data = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://+username:password@server_details:27017/db_name.collection_name?authSource=admin").load()
```

And this will be spark dataframe, no need to convert it.You just need to configure mongodb spark connector.

If you are using notebook write this at the top-

```
 %%configure
{"conf": {"spark.jars.packages": "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.2"}}
```

If you are using spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.pyspark.python=/usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/python3.5 --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.1 file_name.py
```

If you want to write it back to mangoDB, try:

```
data.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append").option("spark.mongodb.output.uri","mongodb://+username:password@server_details:27017/db_name.collection_name?authSource=admin").save()
```

Comment: Could you please also help how to write the data in MongoDB using pyspak? Your suggestion above helped me read from mongodb, though I also have requirement to update the collection from pyspakr. Please suggest

Comment: Please check now. and if you have new data frame to create then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316716/how-can-i-define-an-empty-dataframe-in-pyspark-and-append-the-corresponding-data/61866414#61866414

Comment: I think to write it back to Mongo, it needs to be "option("spark.mongodb.output.uri")"

Comment: Why should we authenticate as admin? Isn't sufficient to use username:password?

Answer (score 2):

By default [pyspark.sql.SQLContext.jsonRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.jsonRDD) will dynamically infer the schema of the given JSON dataset. Columns will be added as new JSON fields are found. This can be slow as every JSON attribute is inspected. Especially if you have 1000 coloumns.

What you could do is to define the schema explicitly instead, given if the data is known *or* only a specific set of fields is needed.

In addition, due to `ObjectId` issue described in [HADOOP-277](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/HADOOP-277) you need to either remove fields containing such incompatible types, or convert to other types. i.e. `str(ObjectId(...))`

For example :

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
import pymongo_spark 
pymongo_spark.activate()
data_rdd = sc.mongoRDD("mongodb://localhost:27017/database.collection")
sqlcontext = SQLContext(sc)

# Define your schema explicitly
schema = StructType([StructField("firstname", StringType()),
                     StructField("lastname", StringType()),
                     StructField("description", StringType())])

# Create a mapper function to return only the fields wanted, or to convert. 
def project(doc):
    return {"firstname": str(doc["firstname"]), 
            "lastname": str(doc["lastname"]), 
            "description": str(doc["description"])}

projected_rdd = data_rdd.map(project)
train_df = sqlcontext.jsonRDD(projected_rdd, schema)
train_df.first()
```

The above snippet was tested in environment: [Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) v1.6.1, [mongo-hadoop spark](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Spark-Usage) v1.5.2

Comment: Hi Wan, good to know about using schema too. I tried it and for 100 columns it didn't make any difference. I will try it for 1000 columns too and will post the results here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's late but this question got `7k` views so I decided to write my answer.

In my idea, it's an excellent job (based on the subject) to load data and then query it with SQL, before going throw the code please keep in mind you have to install the exact same requirements from [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html)

- Development machine versions:

  - operating system: OSX 12.4
  - python: 3.8.9
  - JDK: 1.8.0_292 (openjdk@8)
  - pyspark: 3.2.1

**First**, Install `pyspark`:

```
pip install pyspark
```

Note that if you are on OSX like me you have to use the command with `pip3`.

**Second**, import the libraries:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
```

**Third**, configuration:

```
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().set("spark.jars.packages",
"org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1",
    ).setMaster("local").setAppName("SPARK").setAll([
    ("spark.driver.memory", "3g"),
    ("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
    ])
```

Note that the `spark.driver.memory` and `spark.executor.memory` amoun are custom and depends on your project.

**Fourth**, `SparkContext` and `SQLContext`:

```
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
sqlC = SQLContext(sc)
```

Here I am looking forward to querying the `comments` collection from the `DK` database in my MongoDB, so keep that in mind you have to replace your own MongoDB uri with your port, username, password, database, collection and etc.

```
comments = sqlC.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("spark.mongodb.input.uri",
                                                                      "mongodb://root:root_password@localhost:28018/DK.comments?authSource=admin&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false").load()
comments.createOrReplaceTempView("comments")
```

**Fifth**, querying data:

```
comments = sqlC.sql(
    "SELECT title,body,rate,recommendation_status,is_buyer FROM comments")
comments.show()
```

Now you can simply query your data in my case I queried these attributes:

- title
- body
- rate
- recommendation_status
- is_buyer

**Sixth**, result:

As my database includes Persian comments about products the result of the above query is like this:

[image: result of image]

Hope it helps and thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Without username and password

This worked for database_name = `medicine_catalog` and collection_name = `user_tbl`

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row

input_uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/medicine_catalog.user_tbl"
output_uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/medicine_catalog.user_tbl"

my_spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("Read_write_mongodb")\
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", input_uri)\
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", output_uri)\
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1')\
    .getOrCreate()

#reading from database
df = my_spark.read.format('com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource').load()

#df.printSchema()
#df.show()

#created a data frame of two records
df = my_spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(name = 'Ranjish1', sex = 'male'),
    Row(name = 'Pandey2', sex = 'male')
   ])

#writing to the database
df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append").option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", output_uri).save()
```