# How can I define an empty dataframe in Pyspark and append the corresponding dataframes with it?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I want to read the csv files from a directory, as a pyspark dataframe and then append them into single dataframe. 
Not getting the alternative for this in pyspark, the way we do in pandas.

For example in Pandas, we do:

```
files=glob.glob(path +'*.csv')

df=pd.DataFrame() 

for f in files:
    dff=pd.read_csv(f,delimiter=',')
    df.append(dff)
```

In Pyspark I have tried this but not successful

```
schema=StructType([])
union_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(),schema)

for f in files:
    dff = sqlContext.read.load(f,format='com.databricks.spark.csv',header='true',inferSchema='true',delimiter=',')
    df=df.union_All(dff)
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

One way for getting this done as below in spark 2.1:

```
files=glob.glob(path +'*.csv')

for idx,f in enumerate(files):
    if idx == 0:
        df = spark.read.csv(f,header=True,inferSchema=True)
        dff = df
    else:
        df = spark.read.csv(f,header=True,inferSchema=True)
        dff=dff.unionAll(df)
```

Answer (score 10):

Define schema first, and then you can use unionAll to concatenate new dataframes to the empty one and even run iterations to combine a bunch of dataframes together.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

sc = SparkContext(conf=SparkConf())
spark = SparkSession(sc)     # Need to use SparkSession(sc) to createDataFrame

schema = StructType([
    StructField("column1",StringType(),True),
    StructField("column2",StringType(),True)
])
empty = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)

empty = empty.unionAll(addOndata)
```

Comment: ```empty = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)``` is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The schema should be same when using "unionAll" on 2 dataframes. Therefore, the schema of the empty dataframe should be as per the csv schema.

For eg:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("v1", LongType(), True), StructField("v2", StringType(), False), StructField("v3", StringType(), False)
])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([],schema)
```

Or you can do like this:

```
f = files.pop(0)
df = sqlContext.read.load(f,format='com.databricks.spark.csv',header='true',inferSchema='true',delimiter=',')
for f in files:
    dff = sqlContext.read.load(f,format='com.databricks.spark.csv',header='true',inferSchema='true',delimiter=',')
    df=df.union_All(dff)
```

Comment: the last line of the code should be: df = df.unionAll(dff)

Answer (score 5):

you can get away with an empty DataFrame here.
create an empty list and keep adding the child DataFrames to it. Once you're done with adding all the DataFrames that you want to combine, do a reduce using union to the list and it will combine all of them into one DataFrame.

```
list_of_dfs = []
for i in number_of_dfs:
    list_of_dfs.append(df_i)
combined_df = reduce(DataFrame.union, list_of_dfs)
```

Comment: This will return `NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined`

Comment: you gotta import “reduce” :) https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it. I don't create an empty DataFrame.

```
def concat_spark_iterator(iterator):
    """
    :param iterator: iterator(Spark DataFrame)   
    :return: Concatenated Spark DataFrames
    """

    df = next(iterator)

    for _df in iterator:
        df = df.union(_df)

    return df
```

Answer (score 2):

First define proper schema for your empty dataframe in which you later append your other data.
 For example -

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("phrase",StringType(),True),
    StructField("count_tf",ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField("count", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("tf", DoubleType(), True)
    ])),True)])
empty = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
empty.printSchema()

root 
 |-- phrase: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count_tf: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- count: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tf: double (nullable = true)
```

Then check schema of your dataframe which you need to append in empty. Both schema should be same. Now you can easily append your dataframe in empty dataframe.

```
for f in files:
    dff = sqlContext.read.load(f)
    empty=empty.union(dff)
```